# Yarn cache works or not

Tags: github, hadoop-yarn, github-actions

I have implemented the yarn cache in github actions using https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/master/examples.md#node---yarn but how can I check if it is working or not.

I simply pasted that code in my workflows file.

Comment: you need to run the workflow, that's how you test if it works or not

Comment: btw the code you pasted only describes 2 steps in the workflow; you still need to describe the job the steps will run in, the event that triggers the workflow and the name of the workflow. See https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions and https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows